# Non-destructive transformation + effects Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm not sure I'm using the right language, but I'm stumped on how to google for this. Basically, I want to take a layer containing multiple objects, duplicate it, and apply effects to it. I have to do this four times, but what I really need is to have the original be linked to these new duplicates.

If I shift the size, placement, etc of the shapes, I want the effect duplicates to mimic those changes. I can do this with Effect > Transform, which makes multiple copies that still have the parent's properties linked to them, but I can't target those copies with the various effects I want to do. Like, I want one of the copies to have a free distort and color change which will make a nice shadow. Am I out of luck trying to do this dynamically?

Comment: Too many non-descriptive words for me to understand. Can you clarify, maybe include pictures. I mean you started with layers, then objects, then duplicates (of layers or objects I do not know), then went to shapes, then effect duplicates (no clue what "effect duplicates" are), then to parents. Maybe someone else already understands, but sorry I don't. Voting to close as Unclear.

Comment: Have you tried Symbols, then applying your effects to symbol instances?

Comment: Sorry Ryan! I'll try to show what I mean. I start out with the blue square: http://i.imgur.com/490VwFC.png Then I want to make another copy and free distort and change the color overlay. However, if I make changes to the blue, I want the black and purple to reflect those changes too.

Answer (score 1):

With a vague understanding of the problem, here are some options:

1. Use [Symbols](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/symbols.html), get your base appearance then break or modify as needed.
2. Use [Graphic Styles](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html), get your base appearance, then break or modify as needed.